# magento 2 checkout page terms and condition not working

Tags: magento-2.3

I have Added Terms And Condition On checkout page but after clicking on Place Order button getting 400 bad request. 
Message : 
Payment method : Check / Money order
The order wasn't placed. First, agree to the terms and conditions, then try placing your order again.

But I have Already checked the checkbox. If I remove the checkbox then everything works fine.Thank you

I can see in thei request : /rest/default/V1/guest-carts/fWLWIuvvk5lE23d02fjcgP4rBIo2mtjH/payment-information

agreement_ids: [] is getting blank.

I ahve added these lines below of Billing step inside checkout_index_index.xml file.

```
    <item name="after-place-agreements" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/payment/before-place-order</item>
</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="agreementss" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: Any Idea @anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just disabling the plugin which throws this exception. It seems unnecessary anyway. To do that add this to `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface">
    <plugin name="validate-agreements" disabled="true" />
</type>
```

and run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`